# apt-get autoremove removed files I didn't ask it to remove!

Tags: ros2

So I was trying to install CUDA toolkit so I can use my NVIDIA dedicated GPU in WSL2 but encountered a warning on reboot. I tried to uninstall the toolkit because I thought I'd missed an important step in the guide. I followed the Nvidia guide and it said to use the following commands:
https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#notices
(Scroll down to heading 18)

To remove CUDA Toolkit:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove "*cuda*" "*cublas*" "*cufft*" "*cufile*" "*curand*" \
 "*cusolver*" "*cusparse*" "*gds-tools*" "*npp*" "*nvjpeg*" "nsight*" "*nvvm*"
```

To remove NVIDIA Drivers:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove "*nvidia*" "libxnvctrl*"
```

To clean up the uninstall:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Suddenly I noticed my ROS-Humble files also being removed! I never asked for those files to be removed and then suddenly my whole dev environment stopped working. I couldn't run executables.

I managed to find a fix for the executables using:
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8952 the-moog's comment:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo :WSLInterop:M::MZ::/init:PF > /usr/lib/binfmt.d/WSLInterop.conf'
sudo systemctl restart systemd-binfmt
```

So now after reinstalling ROS2 Humble (ros-humble-desktop) it is back to normal but I would like to prevent this from happening again. There must be some dependency causing autoremove to select ROS2. Has anyone encountered this issue? Is there a way to prevent autoremove from doing this again perhaps by setting all ROS2 files to be marked as manually installed?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ohh is it because it is a desktop version of ROS2?

This page shed some light on it: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1366752/apt-get-autoremove-wants-to-remove-1000-packages-and-everything

> This happens most commonly when folks bolt a Desktop onto a Minimal
> install. But it can happen when you bolt ANY kind of major stack onto
> an Ubuntu system.